# clearTimeout is not working in React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native

I have four screens A (HomePage), B, C, D

Each of screens have a function that will be triggered when the screen `onStart` or `onResume`, I achieve it by react-redux.

```
countdownToFirstScreen = () => {
    this.timeOut = setTimeout(()=> {
      clearTimeout(this.timeOut); // clearTimeout before navigate next screen
      this.props.leaveTheScreenTime(); // change for some redux store boolean
      this.props.navigation.navigate('A');
    }, 9000);    
  }
```

If user click `<Button />` before countdown finish, I set the clearTimeout too.

```
<Button 
  onPress={() => { 
    clearTimeout(this.timeOut);
    this.props.navigation.navigate('nextScreen');
  }
/>
```

It is working when I just navigate between A and B and C.

My issue happens when I try to navigate from C to D.

C screen function `countdownToFirstScreen` will be triggered eventhough I click the `<Button />` on C screen.

Any one knows what happened with my `setTimeout` and `clearTimeout`?

Comment: Is `this` referencing the same object?

Comment: You most likely unmount your component and when you route back you create new reference on mount and you never point to an same object again.

Comment: Hmm... I use the same name `this.timeout` in all screens.  It may be this problem ?

Comment: @JimiPajala I can not understand your meaning, because C `countdownToFirstScreen` will be triggered if I just navigate A -> B -> C -> D. It doesn't route back any screen in this case.

Comment: Share simplified structure and code example. It is very hard to grasp your situation otherwise, example in https://codesandbox.io

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like you may run into scoping issues as `this` in the `setTimeout` callback may have a different context than `this.timeOut` and thus the timer is not being cleared. Ideally you want a setup where you track the timer in some global component like your `AppComponent` which is on every screen, with a setup like:

```
componentWillMount () {
   // Add your listener
   DeviceEventEmitter.addListener('timer', this.clearTimer.bind(this));
}

componentDidMount () {
  startTimer()
}

componentWillUnMount () {
  clearTimer()
}

startTimer () {
 this.timer = this.setTimeout(() => {
   this.props.navigation.navigate('A');
 },9000);

clearTimer () {
 // Handle an undefined timer rather than null
 this.timer !== undefined ? this.clearTimeout(this.timer) : null;
}
```

Comment: Yes, I change my code with DeviceEventEmitter, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 10):

Using **React-Hooks** and **Functional Components** ... things are alot easier...

An effect with empty-deps `[]` simulates `componentDidMount`, and its cleanUp-callback simulates `componentWillUnmount`

```
  const timerRef = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    timerRef.current = setTimeout(() => {
      /** Your logic goes here */
    }, 9000);

    return () => {
      if (timerRef.current) {
        clearTimeout(timerRef.current);
      }
    };
  }, []);
```